# Transparency in plotted surfaces

Tags: octave, transparency, alpha, surface, surf

I'm using Octave 7.2.0-1 on linux.

When plotting surfaces which overlap (both with facealpha<1) Octave only shows the axes as a "see-through", not the surface which is "behind":

```
[ xs, ys, zs ] = sphere( 20 );
surf( xs, ys, zs, 'facealpha', 0.5, 'edgealpha', 0.5, 'facecolor', 'r' );
hold on
surf( xs+1, ys+1, zs , 'facealpha',0.5, 'edgealpha', 0.5, 'facecolor', 'g');
```

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Acoording to [this discussion](https://octave.discourse.group/t/transparent-surface-with-patch/2943/3), plotting the green sphere first may solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I've been experimenting with surf & facealpha & it seems like a hit-or-miss: different combinations for the order of the plotted elements should be tried until the desired effect is (hopefully) achieved.

Comment: The elements should be plotted from back to front